# Have Google Speech to text API always return numbers as written text

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

We are using the google speech to text api for a vocabulary learning app. We experience that the api returns sometimes numbers as written text and sometimes as numbers.

E.g. 10 vs ten

Did anyone figure out a way to have the google speech api return any number in any sentences always as written text?

Comment: I think that it should rather always be written text, to achieve numbers `class tokens` should be used. What API is used? Is it possible to be replicated? Are you able to provide such test audio sample?

Comment: We are basically using the implementation from here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text where you can test there demo at "Put Speech-to-Text into action". If I say "fifteen" Google will return "15"

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have tested it as well with `gcloud`. The same result. I went trough the documentation and didn't found anything like that. Have you tried to do it with some additional library like Python's [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/)...

Comment: Thanks for your time. I wanted to avoid using extra libraries to achieve the desired result. However, it really looks like there is no option to force this behaviour.